# Std::map throws bad_alloc when making new entry in another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm using GCC 4.4.7. I have a map of type `map<int, string>`. I find whenever I'm trying to access it from another thread, `terminate called without an active exception` is thrown. It works when I initialize a entry in the main thread and then access in it another thread. I reproduced the error using this code

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>   
#include <thread>

using namespace std;



class A {
public:
    void start() {
        while(1) {
            mp["random"] = 2;
        }
    }
private:
    map< int , string > mp_1;
    map<string, int> mp;

};

int main() {
    A * a = new A();
    std::thread t;
    cout << "opening new thread" << std::endl;
    t = std::thread(std::bind(&A::start, a));
}
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Your thread never produces observable behavior and never terminates. See http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.progress#1

Comment: Undefined behavior. `main()` exits, calling `std::thread`'s destructor. Joinable threads must be `join()`ed, before their destructor gets called. This has nothing to do with your map.

Comment: Have a look [at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread). If the thread isn't joined or detached on destruction std::terminate is called.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need `std::bind` here; `std::thread` is smart enough to handle this itself: `std:thread(&A::start, a)`.

Comment: And while I'm analyzing code, there's no need to `new` the `A` object; just create it as an auto object. And initialize the thread object with it: `A a; std::thread t(&A::start, a);` or `std::thread t(&A::start, &a)` if you want the pointer.